# Google Sheest COUNTIF returning wrong value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this spreadsheet where a COUNTIF formula is working weird. Somehow, the counting is wrong.

[Find the sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oCjjuOIcVBkMIDnhltC6-KRFrXqDPCMDyc9BjMYMCGI/edit?usp=sharing)

Cell E3 in the tab "Sheets2" has a formula that should return a result of 1160 (it's the number of URLs in the tab "√" in column F that are associated with a date between today and one year ago). But, as you can see, the result given is 1146.

I can't figure out what's the problem here. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I think you misclicked your comment on my answer as an edit suggestion. Glad to know that it worked on your end. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

use in E3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 QUERY({REGEXEXTRACT('Import Backlinks'!F2:F, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(A3:A, 1, 0))), 'Import Backlinks'!K2:K}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col2 <= date '2021-2-15'
    and Col2 >= date '2020-2-15' 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"), 2, 0), 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Your current formula checks for the dates 2/15/2020 00:00:00 up to 2/15/2021 00:00:00. Anything later than 2/15/2021 will not be counted. This means, if the date 2/15/2021 in the 1st tab of your sheet includes a time which is past 00:00:00, that entry will not be counted.

### Solution

To solve this, you can use "<2/16/2020" instead of "<=2/15/2020" in your formula. It should look like this:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(A3:A),(COUNTIFS('Import Backlinks'!$K$2:$K,"<2/16/2021",'Import Backlinks'!$K$2:$K,">=2/15/2020",'Import Backlinks'!F2:F,"*" & A3:A & "*")
),"")))
```

This resulted to this:
[image]